# SQL CE and StructureMap

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, repository, sql-server-ce, structuremap

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 3 application using Entity Framework CF, StructureMap and SQL CE.
Here's the code:

**Repository**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Foo> Foo { get; set; }
}

public class FooRepository : IFooRepository
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext db;

    public FooRepository(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public List<Foo> GetAll()
    {
        return db.Foo.ToList();
    }
}
```

**StructureMap config**

```
For<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
    .Use<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .Ctor<string>("connectionString")
    .EqualToAppSetting("DbConnectionString");

For<IFooRepository>().Use<FooRepository>();
```

Everything works fine, but once application becomes inactive and I call `IFooRepository.GetAll()` after 10-15 minutes, I get the following exception:

```
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: 
Internal error: Unable to successfully execute disk IO on the file system.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could this be some kind of timeout problem?

Comment: How are your connectionstring?